# Set javascript variable from one iframe to another

Tags: javascript

Trying pass variable from one iframe to another. Sound weird but I made  a picture to make it clear:

[image]

My first try to add new srcrip to the new iframe. Looks like its work, but new variable undefined.

```
var creativeFrame = parentDocument.getElementById('iframe2');
var creativeWindow = parentDocument.getElementById('iframe2').contentWindow;
var creativeDocument = creativeFrame.document;

var myFunction = function() {
 var iFrameHead = creativeFrame.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
 var myscript = creativeBody.createElement('script');
 myscript.type = 'text/javascript';
 myscript.text = 'var a = 2';
 iFrameHead.appendChild(myscript);
};
if(creativeFrame.addEventListener) {
 creativeFrame.addEventListener('load', myFunction, true);
} else if(creativeFrame.attachEvent) {
 creativeFrame.attachEvent('onload', myFunction);
}
</script>
```

Comment: yoi can do stuff like iframe.contentWindow.property="test" outside and in the iframe window.property to retrieve it  but I want to urge you to think twice about implementing this since an iframe is supposed to always be able to live on its own

Answer (score 1):

[Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is the recommended way to pass data from one [Window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) (tab, window, iframe...) to another. Minimal use case:

1. An event listener must be present in the script of the iframe: `window.addEventListener('message', console.log);`
2. The parent window, given a window reference to the iframe, can then send message to the iframe: `myIframe.postMessage('hello world', '*')`